# Finding two integers that fit a requirement

Tags: geometry, integers

I have three variables $a,b,s$. I need to find two more variables $c,d$. $a/b= c/d$ and $abs =cd$. $c$ and $d have to be integers, and in the case that they're not, they must be whatever integers are closest to making the equation true.

How can I solve for $c$and $d$?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Could you show us what you've tried so far, and layout your formation?

Comment: $c=\sqrt {a^2s} $ and $d=b\sqrt {s} $.  As for them being integers ... would you like the green straight lines to be purple and wavy looking?

Comment: Using these you can easily get b^2s=d^2 and a^2s=c^2

Comment: To satisfy all requirements for any a,b,s is impossible.  To find the best way to fudge could depend on what the original problem is.  c and d *must* be integers we can maybe fudge how close c/d =a/b or abs = cd and for that maybe we can fudge a,b,and,s?  There's no real formula for fudging.

Answer (score 0):

You have two equations and two variables you wish to solve for so solve simultaneously.

$$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}\text{ and }abs=cd$$

Rewrite the second one to: $d=\frac{abs}{c}$ and substitute this into the first:

$$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c^2}{abs}$$

$$c^2=a^2s$$

$$c=a\sqrt{s}$$

Similar steps leads to:

$$d=b\sqrt{s}$$

As to whether they are integers or not, it will depend on your $a$, $b$ and $s$. Your problem seems to be over specified and the underlying (original) problem may make a good new question.